# PHP Prepared Statement Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

The code below only returns one result. The remaining five results are blank. How can I return all rows?

```
foreach($dates as $date){

    if($stmt->prepare("SELECT event FROM calendar WHERE date = ?")) {

        $stmt->bind_param('i',$date);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($event);

        $stmt->store_result();

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo $event;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a " from your SQL query

Comment: You should move the `prepare` statement before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: whilst it might sound stupid, have you checked to see there is more then 1 item in the $dates array and if so that the other 4 actually match an entry? (check size of $stmt->fetch())

Comment: The array has five elements and they do match. Am I doing this the right way using a prepared statement?

Comment: That's not what you said in the question (1 valid result, 5 blanks). How many times does the loop iterate?

Comment: @Mr.Jones: Don't edit your question to reflect the answer.  When people read this in the future, it won't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You closed the prepared statement in the first execution of foreach loop.

Move your `$stmt->prepare("SELECT event FROM calendar WHERE date = ?")` outside of the foreach loop and

`$stmt->close()` outside of foreach  loop